# Is it possible to do a part time MRes alongside a PhD?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, masters, united-kingdom

In my university you are allowed to work 20 hours part time alongside your PhD. My PhD is in engineering but my background is maths and physics and I find the PhD relatively light work due to my background. I am still interested in mathematical physics and would want to take my career in that direction. I thought that if I enrol in an MRes degree in mathematical physics alongside my PhD in engineering it could make me a more competitive applicant, especially if I get some publications from the MRes.

Does my PhD supervisor need to know about this plan of mine? If you get a part-time job along-side your PhD for example, you are not required to disclose this information to them.

When applying for the MRes degree, would I need to say that I am currently doing a PhD and could this affect the decision?

Finally, how does a typical MRes work in terms of the logistics of meeting your supervisor? At the moment my PhD supervision meetings are all online and I do not need to go to campus at all. Could it be the same for the MRes?

Note: an MRes is a Master's of Research most typically found in UK universities. It differs from an MA or MSc in that the emphasis is on the student doing their own research rather than taking taught courses. It is therefore referred to as a "Master's by research" as opposed to a "taught Master's". For more information, see here: https://career-advice.jobs.ac.uk/studentship-advice/which-masters-degree-mres-or-ma-msc/

Comment: Please explain, what does Mres mean?  Also, you should not assume people can understand the various TLA that you are using.  Some here do not have English as a first language so it is better to use standard capitalization, verbs and a lot fewer abreviations.

Comment: apologies edited, thought Mres stands for masters by research as apose to MSc say, ta

Comment: Perhaps Masters by Research is a British thing?

Comment: Why do you need to enroll in an MRes to do research in a related discipline to your PhD? Why not talk to your PhD supervisor to check they're on board and then find some collaborators (either at your own uni or elsewhere) to do some mathematical physics work with? I think you would almost certainly have to disclose that you're currently a PhD student when applying for an MRes and probably your current and prospective universities will have rules limiting or prohibiting dual enrolment. Bottom line: talk to your PhD supervisor before doing anything.

Comment: I also edited your post to make the questions clearer, please feel free to edit my edits if I got something wrong. I also added the UK tag, as I assume that is where you are studying.

Comment: if i do that, and they do not want to do any mathematical physics, what is the worst outcome that could be? just a harsh relationship? like they couldnt' take away the funding righttt?

Comment: @astronat , but if you're allowed to work part-time and the hours are within the limits of both the PhD and MRes, I can't see how they could really,

Comment: Working to earn money is not the same as performing research to earn a degree. When you submit your PhD thesis you will have to sign a declaration stating that you have not submitted the work for any other academic qualification. If your MRes is in a similar field to your PhD it may be very difficult to maintain that separation and hence honestly sign such a declaration. Lying could lead to one or both of your degrees being revoked later on.

Comment: No, your supervisor (if you are in the UK, are you?) cannot just "take away the funding", as your studentship is likely provided via the department, university or research council rather than controlled by the supervisor directly. There's nothing wrong with having diverse research interests and wanting to pursue them. I don't see any reason to expect a negative reaction or harsh relationship, but you know them better than we do.

Comment: I may speculate that instead of giving their blessing for you to go off and do some other research, your supervisor suggest or assign you more work in their discipline. (Your feeling that the workload is light is likely a function of how far through the PhD you are. I spent the first three months of mine mostly reading and feeling bored -- "is this it?" I thought. The workload increased steadily after that, until the final six months before submission where I was working on three projects plus writing my thesis. No time (or shred of desire) for a second degree then! You may find the same.)

Comment: hiyah many thanks for your reply. wel I'm in a year in, and when I say 'light' as I say i think its the difference between my maths/psysics background- alot of mathematical physics stuff comapated to fluid mechanics, within an enginnering department, which could only get heavy in terms of ' workload' . as far, telling them it's light work, no way do I plan to, if i want to do a mres, tht would be a very stupid move. as far potential overlap and declaration, no, none at all, different subjects completely.